# Can't backup with MariaDB Console

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to take a backup of a database.  I open up the MariaDB client console on windows 10, enter root password and then enter this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> mysqldump database_name > backup.sql;
```

It returns this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump database_name > backup.sql' at line 1
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_name > file.sql
```

before logging to database (new CLI window). You will have to enter root password after this command

You should be able to run this command in any CLI, like CMD.exe or Git Bash - depending on the way you installed things on your machine. I hope this helps

Comment: My confusion was that mysqldump is a binary and not a command.  I needed to update my PATH variable to point to bin folder in windows